# How To Disable (or Remove) “All Comments, Published, and Trash” in WP Dashboard for non admins

Tags: php, wordpress, function

So I have found the way to remove all of that in Posts (for non admins) with the following line:

```
/**
 * Remove the 'all', 'publish', 'future', 'sticky', 'draft', 'pending', 'trash' 
 * views for non-admins
 */
add_filter( 'views_edit-post', function( $views )
{
    if( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
        return $views;

    $remove_views = [ 'all','publish','future','sticky','draft','pending','trash' ];

    foreach( (array) $remove_views as $view )
    {
        if( isset( $views[$view] ) )
            unset( $views[$view] );
    }
    return $views;
} );
```

Now I want to remove all of those in Comments as well.

I can't find the answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use the same function, but with the `views_edit-comments` filter.

Comment: It worked, thanks. One more thing. is it possible when you click on Comments it will automatically open just "Mine". Because now when you click on Comments, I can see all of the comments. You need to click on "Mine" to filter just my own comments...

Comment: As far as I understand, by default it opens "All". So even if you remove all of that, it still shows comments from"All". I wonder if there's a code that when you click on "Comments" it will open "Mine" for non admins.

Comment: But, in this way, would you like to the users have access to others' comments when clicking on "Approved", for example? Or a non-admin should never see a comment from another user, even on Pending, Approved, Spam, etc?

Comment: Yes, basically I'm trying to achieve, so that the a non admin (in my case an author) would only see his own posts and his own comments (in the dashboard). No other user data would be visible. I have managed to do so with Posts, The only thing that's left is to manage how to go to "Mine" by default when a non admin clicks on "Comments" in the dashboard.

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, just add another `add_filter` with "views_edit-comments".

To always show only own comments to a non-admin user, use the follow code:

```php
add_action( 'current_screen', 'wp_66446729_filter_comments', 10, 2 );

function wp_66446729_filter_comments( $screen )
{
    if ( current_user_can('administrator') )
        return;

    add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'wp_66446729_list_own_comments_only', 10, 1 );
}

function wp_66446729_list_own_comments_only( $clauses )
{
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if ($user_id) {
      $clauses->query_vars['user_id'] = $user_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. worked like a charm. thanks for your effort Lucius!

Comment: Just a little thing: the code only prevents users from seeing others' comments on that specific screen, they can still see comments through URL, for example.

Comment: that will do the job, that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks again.